# Nvidia Driver Install Fails: unable to locate the kernel source

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel

I'm running Ubuntu 14.05 and I would like to install cuda_7.5.18.  I tried to run the driver install file from Nvidia `cuda_7.5.18_linux.run` and failed.  The error message is:

The driver installation is unable to locate the kernel source. Please make sure that the kernel source packages are installed and set up correctly.

I did this, but it did not help: `apt-get source linux-source`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.
The solution was to turn off secure boot in the BIOS.
For my ASUS motherboard, the procedure was:
**BIOS -> Advanced Mode -> Boot >- Secure Boot -> Key Management -> “Clear Secure Boot keys”**

Comment: it will be different for every device though. This is more of a comment imho

Answer (score 0):

a temporary solution for me was to downgrade the kernel which comes with a current fresh installation of Ubuntu 16.04 (you can check with uname -r):

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-4.13.0-26-generic
sudo apt-get purge linux-headers-4.13.0-26-generic
```

Update initramfs image:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u
```

Reboot and try again.